# Incremental build with continuous integration server

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, build-automation

Does any of the continuous integration servers support incremental builds or filtering mechanism? For example, I want to configure some kind of filtering (as I call it) so that committing file to the specific folder will not cause full (clean) build triggering, but will cause only incremental build. By 'incremental build' I mean process that will put only committed files to the required place and all application would not need to be rebuilt from scratch. Working with images is good example of the case when we need such filtering and thus incremental builds: why do we need to rebuild whole application if only images have been changed? What we need to do is just place images to the dedicated place on server.

Comment: What does a full build cost you?  Is it just taking a long time? (how long?)  Or is there something else about a full build you are trying to avoid?

Comment: @Zarigani: build takes 15 minutes. it really costs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It could be implemented by the CI server which allows customizing build on commit preferences. It will require specifying all the folders which require full rebuild if directory content has been changed.

Answer (score 3):

That is typically implemented by the build tool(s) called by the CI server (make, nmake, msbuild, etc.).

Comment: This is the best answer: indeed the build logic should have nothing to do with the CI server.

Answer (score 2):

Hudson, nativity supports SVN UPDATE command, than you need to tuneup you's build scripts, to do Build instead of Rebuild command.

In general, I would say that every CI server supports this, using custom build scripts.

Answer (score 0):

easyCIS makes the build ASAP by default. It does pull only the changed files from VCS and does incremental build, if tasks are not configured otherwise. That being said, easyCIS supports this even without custom build scripts.